# CAST TEXT as INTEGER

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a CHAR column that contains messy OCR'd scan of printed integers.

I need to do SUM() operators on that column.  But I'm unable to cast properly.

```
;Good
sqlite> select CAST("123" as integer);
123

;No Good, should be '323999'
sqlite> select CAST("323,999" as integer);
323
```

I believe SQLite interprets the comma as marking the end of the "[the longest possible prefix of the value that can be interpreted as an integer number](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)"

I prefer to avoid the agony of writing python scripts to do data cleaning on this column.  Is there any clever way to do it strictly with SQL?

Comment: What value do you want that converted to?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  the integer 323999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to ignore commas, then remove them before the conversion:

```
select cast(replace('323,999', ',', '') as integer)
```